# Kartik Gridview conflict with my templates menu

Tags: yii2

I have a template that i was using for my project.

Look at the picture below:

[image]
This is when i am not using the kartikGrid. the dropdown menu running as well as the template want.

look at the image below:
[image]

this is when i use kartik, the dropdown menu not running anymore.
can some body tell me why it happen.

The template using different bootsrap version with kartik.

thaks.
Hope some body help me.

Answer (score 4):

Imaginaroom, that did the trick for me thank you.

My top menu wasn't responding (direct link, or drop down menu) after kartik was used. I added an `id` to my menu widget and it did the trick.

```
echo Nav::widget([
    'id' => 'topMenuID',
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
    'items' => $menuItems,
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Manually assign different ids to all widgets, so there won't be any conflicts. 
If you don't assign ids to widgets, yii gives them one automatically, but the problem occures when loading data with ajax or pjax, then Yii cannot know which ids are already used in the page.

Every widget in Yii2 has a property 'id' that you can assign in configuration array when calling a widget.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in layout or page that has problem:

```
$this->registerJs( "$(document).ready(function() { $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown(); });", View::POS_END, 'ecommerceProductJs' );
```